# How to find out the heated IC's or CMOS in a circuit automatically.

Tags: integrated-circuit, thermal

How to find out the heated IC's or CMOS in a circuit automatically. Because its very hard to find the heated IC's by touching each and everything. ca anyone suggest me any method to find it out?

Comment: Thermal camera?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your funds, but a FLIR handheld camera, or the FLIR iPhone case does the trick really well. I think the FLIR One iPhone case is under $300. Alternatively, an infrared no-contact thermometer could work as well. Good thing about the FLIR systems, is you can point it at a board and not only see what's hot, but live temperature changes at the same time.

Comment: http://flir.com/flirone/

Comment: http://flir.com/instruments/content/?id=64755

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, i don't think there is an easy way to find out without using equipment. All i can think of is thermal imaging or infrared.

But try to focus on your design instead of things heating up on  your circuit, components that have those screw slots for heat sinks should only be the ones heating up and should be compensated with the application of a heat sink. If any other component heats up unusually like resistors for example, then there must be something wrong with your circuit.

Take care :) and try not to make things explode.